# sqlite: Does sqlite support storing vectors (an array of data)?

Tags: database, sqlite

Say if I have a vector of data, is it possible to specify a field to store it? So that I can store and retrieve a serialized data?

Comment: Do you want to store a *vector* (which consists of multiple values), or *serialized* data (which is a single string/blob)?

Comment: Sorry for replying late! Just saw your comment. I wanted to store a vector (of multiple values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not directly support vectors.

To store a vector as one of the [supported data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), you have to serialize it first.

Comment: Thank you CL. Really appreciate it.